# curl hanging, despite connect-timeout and max-time

Tags: linux, curl

I have some scripts retrieving resources (image files etc) using system calls to curl. Occasionally, these will fail to finish, and will show as pipe_w in process listings.

```
F S UID        PID  PPID  C PRI  NI ADDR SZ WCHAN  STIME TTY          TIME CMD
0 S root      4378  4086  0  82   2 - 16002 pipe_w Jan10 ?        00:00:00 curl -JO --max-time 60 --connect-timeout 60 https://address/path/to/resource?identifier=tag
```

If I understand correctly, I can use connect-timeout to set the # of seconds to try and make the connection, and max-time to limit the amount of time to wait for response from the remote machine.

```
curl -JO --max-time 60 --connect-timeout 60 https://address/path/to/resource?identifier=tag
```

Any suggestions as to how I can force curl to continue past this? Or pointers on what might cause this?

This is using curl 7.21.0, on a stock ubuntu 10.10.

Comment: What do you mean with "continue past this"? Is `curl` called many time by a pipe with xargs?

Comment: curl is run in an explicit loop in a bash script:
`urlproducer | while read line; do curl $line; done `

Comment: and what's the problem? Do you want to retry?

Comment: Retry the current url if feasible. Abandon and continue with next url would be fine as well. _Not_ indefinitely waiting for input (from the remote server?). 

Understanding would be a nice bonus.

Comment: AFAIK your script already should abandon and continue with the next url. I've tried by myself and it works. Anyway... i'm using a 7.15.5 curl CLI and i got no -J parameter. Maybe is affecting your line command in some way?

Comment: When running supervised, it also works for me. When in batch, it will occasionally remain pending, after a few score successful retrievals.

Comment: The -J option is specified [here](http://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html#-J), and is supposed to read and apply the supplied Content-Disposition header.